# parse xml from another domain with php

Tags: php, xml, cross-domain

I want to parse a xml document which is located on another domain.
I want to do this with PHP.
Is it possible?

I've already try simpleXML but it doesn't seems to work.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. What exactly isn't working? What errors are you getting? Can you show some code?

Comment: The answer to your question is "yes", however I get the impression that that's not what you're looking for.  What have you tried?

Comment: oops sorry

<?php

if (file_exists('http://www.stevymahy.com/xml/test.xml')) {
 $xml = simplexml_load_file('http://www.stevymahy.com/xml/test.xml');

 print_r($xml);
} else {
 exit('Cannot open the xml file.');
}
?>

Answer (score 3):

WEll first of all: http://www.stevymahy.com/xml/test.xml has malformed XML. You will not be able to parse this document until its fixed.

## Whats up there now

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <mahy>
    <!-- Diaporama -->
        <diaporama duree="4">
        <photo fichier="/admin/uploads/stevy01_001.jpg"></photo>
        <photo fichier="/admin/uploads/stevy05_001.jpg"></photo>
        <photo fichier="/admin/uploads/stevy06_001.jpg"></photo>
        <photo fichier="/admin/uploads/DSC_8133-Modifier.jpg"></photo>
        <photo fichier="/admin/uploads/appuyevelo.jpg"></photo>
        <photo fichier="/admin/uploads/atriumplus.jpg"></photo>
        <photo fichier="/admin/uploads/balancoirine.jpg"></photo>
    </diaporama>

    <!-- Biographie -->
    <bio textetaille="16" ><![CDATA[jhkjdhgkjdhgjksdghkjshgjkshdgjkhsdgjksdhgjksdhgkj]]></bio>
```

It just trails off... EDIT: I've posted the full XML. It doesn't trail off (anymore?). However the diaporama and bio elements must be contained in a common root node. so maybe wrap everything in `<root>`

## After you get that fixed

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php

```
    // Get the contents of the XML
    $str_xml = file_get_contents('http://www.stevymahy.com/xml/test.xml');

    // Parse the XML
    $obj_xml = new SimpleXMLElement($str_xml);

    // ...do something with the parsed XML object
```

Comment: Check to see if your XML is valid: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.stevymahy.com%2Fxml%2Ftest.xml&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0